# Writing '<' in HTML

Tags: html

I started learning HTML a little while back and now I have hit a snag regarding displaying '<'. This is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test html file</title>
<body>
<h1>Sample Heading</h1>
<pre> This is some sample text. Some more text. The pre tag
      preserves formatting. 
      Is a<b?
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is locally stored and rendered on my local browser. I expect it should display the text as is, preserving line breaks and whitespace as stated [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_pre)

But it doesn't display that, instead it renders everything upto and including 'a'. I understand that the problem is due to '<' being intepreted as the start of a tag, and I am supposed to escape that somehow, but I couldn't find the appropriate syntax for that. Help? Also, what are some other good sources for learning html?

Comment: read the next chapters . (HTML Entities)

Comment: @ShaPesar yeah HTML Entities was linked in the answers. thanks :) I hurried I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn about [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). Code

```
a&lt;b
```

Comment: +1 for the link. Another poster simple wrote `&lt` expecting that `<` is the only thing I will need.

Comment: @Sabyasachi, “<” was the only thing you asked about. You do not need to learn about HTML entities to use `&lt;`. And if you read about them, you should consult specifications or reliable references.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I believe my question was about the general idea of escaping special characters. While apparently the notion of escape sequences doesn't exist in html, entities provide that functionality from what I gathered after some googling.

Answer (score 4):

Use `&lt;`

```
<pre> This is some sample text. Some more text. The pre tag
  preserves formatting. 
  Is a&lt;b?
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `<` with `&lt;`.

You can also find other Special characters codes used in Math [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-math.htm).

Comment: I understand. New user restrictions are a pain in the ass. Consider upvoting my question? Yeah I know it's cheap but if I cross 200 my new user restrictions on other SE sites get lifted too. :p

Comment: I just checked your profile. I'd give you another +1 if I could for the yoda. :D

Comment: Here you go :) Just did

Answer (score 0):

Here this the code use this same code it will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test html file</title>
<body>
<h1>Sample Heading</h1>
<pre> This is some sample text. Some more text. The pre tag
  preserves formatting. 
  Is a&lt;b?
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```